# Finding paths from the result of max flow

Tags: algorithms, graphs, network-flow

Suppose that I have run maxflow algorithm on a graph G and, as a result, I have a set of edges with flow on them.
I would like to enumerate all possible sets of paths that comprise the maxflow.
That is, each set of paths will make the max flow.
But I suspect there could be multiple set of such paths.

Comment: Can you edit the question to clarify exactly what you are looking for?  What does it mean for a set of paths to "comprise the maxflow" or "make the maxflow"?  (For example: Do the paths have to be disjoint?  Do they have to add up to equal the total flow amount?)  I don't understand how I would judge a candidate solution to tell whether it actually is what you want or not.  Can you be more precise?  Also, can you tell us what approaches you have tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

Give the edges some value of priority. Once you have run a given maxflox algorithm, reduce the priority of a given edge by the amount of flow which got through the last time. This way edges which have gotten flow through them the last time running the algorithm will not be chosen as the first flow first this time and another way, if any, will be produced.